# Codeigniter Ajax Delete a record and return available record count

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

Below is my html, ajax and database script to delete a record from database,

HTML

```
<input type="file" name="gallery[]" id="gallery" data-maxupload="<?php echo $maxupload; ?>" multiple="">
<div> 
<img src="..." class="item-1768"> <span class="del_button-" id="del-1768">X</span>
........
</div>
```

AJAX

```
$("body").on("click", ".del_button", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var clickedID = this.id.split('-');
     var DbNumberID = clickedID[1];
     var myData = 'recordToDelete='+ DbNumberID; 
     var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
    $('.item_'+DbNumberID).addClass( "sel" ); 
    $(this).hide(); 
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: base_url + "client/delete_gallery_image",
      dataType: "text",
      data:myData,
      success:function(response){
        $('.item_'+DbNumberID).fadeOut();
        console.log(response);
      },
      error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(thrownError);
      }
      });
  });
```

Model,

```
public function delete_gallery_image($id){
        $this->db->delete('employer_gallery', array('id' => $id));
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }
```

The basic idea of this code is to allow user to upload only 5 files. As because of dynamic ajax deletion i'm not getting the realtime count of records. The above code working well on deleting a record. Now i would like to return the remaining rows in database.

So in model, i've tried to use something like this,

```
public function delete_gallery_image($id){
        $this->db->delete('employer_gallery', array('id' => $id));
        $sql = " SELECT * FROM (`employer_gallery`) where user_id = $id";
        $query = $this->db->query ( $sql );
        return $query->num_rows ();
    }
```

If i get a count i can assign it to variable $maxupload. So that i can do some validation on  file selection. But the above model is not working, it's giving me a 500 internal server error.

Any way to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function delete_gallery_image($id) {
    $this->db->delete ( 'employer_gallery', array (
            'id' => $id 
    ) );

    /* Flush the DB cache */
    $this->db->flush_cache ();

    /* $sql = " SELECT * FROM (`employer_gallery`) where user_id = $id"; */

    $this->db->select ( '*' );
    $this->db->from ( 'employer_gallery' );
    return $rowcount = $query->num_rows ();
}
```

Comment: @Birla Is it possible to use $id ? so that i can use where condition **where user_id = $id**

Comment: if you are using the session for the user it is easy to get the user id from the session, otherwise we need to pass an additional parameters.